# Nuxt.js - get cookie inside plugin

Tags: javascript, cookies, nuxt.js

I had a Vue.JS application and use axios as a HTTP client by just importing its instance into the components (like this):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import cookies from '~/components/cookies.js';
var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost.api/',
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
  'Authorization': cookies.get('token',''),
  'X-Refresh-Token': cookies.get('refreshtoken'),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
})

export default api;
```

...

```
import api from '~components/api.js'
```

Cookies were obtained from document.cookie.
But now I moved to Nuxt and document is not defined during server rendering. So, how can I get cookies from the server request? (or even dynamically change token in the process)

Comment: Please read carefully you will understand how to use , https://medium.com/@eddybordi/nuxt-js-ssr-authentication-8a6afba26533

Comment: Maybe this doc help for you: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-external-jwt